# Using RegexBuddy on htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to convert an htaccess file from Drupal into some custom rules on IIS. I have examples of helpful htaccess files and also have access to RegexBuddy, but I don't know which language I should select for the engine to help me understand the rewrite condition rules better? Sorry if it's an obvious question. Thanks for any assistance.

Jason

Comment: I'm not familiar with Drupal, RegexBuddy, or IIS. Those might be more appropriate tags for this question, since the issue seems very dependent on them.

Comment: If you are asking about selecting a regex engine in RegexBuddy, you can probably use any advanced engine such as Perl if you want fine control or complex rules.

Comment: You also might find regex101.com useful